# Fetch within promise, sporadical reversed chain order

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, chaining

I am chaining two calls to a function that uses fetch and returns a promise.

The calls sometimes arrive in the wrong order, reversed.

I assume my function code is wrong, derived from a bad understanding of either promises, fetch, or both.

This is the function code, simplified:

```
function shop(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch('/shop', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({id: id}) ,
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json '}
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      })
  })
}
```

I chain the function in this manner:

```
shop('potatoe')
.then(shop('mushrooms'));
```

As explained, these two sometimes arrive in the wrong order, with mushrooms being shopped before potatoes.

May I have my returns or resolve() wrongly written in the shop() function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `.then` takes a callback as its argument, while `shop('mushrooms')` is a promise. You want `() => shop('mushrooms')`

Comment: Also avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could give an example of how the code matches such antipattern. Having fetch, with its own chain, within the promise, confuses me.

Comment: Yes, having `fetch` with it promise chain within the `new Promise` executor is exactly the problem - it's confusing and doesn't handle errors properly. Just write `function shop(id) { return fetch(…).then(…).then(function (data) { console.log(data); return data; }); }`

Comment: This meaning I don't need to resolve fetch, as it resolves itself internally when returning ?

Comment: Every promise is responsible for resolving itself internally, regardless what you do with it (`return`ing, chaining `.then()`) or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you call `shop('mushrooms')` immediately, synchronously. You didn't *pass* a callback to the `then` method, but instead *executed* what would be the intended callback. So change the main code to:

```
shop('potatoe')
.then(() => shop('mushrooms'));
```

This solves your problem.

However, you are creating a useless promise in your function. The `fetch().then().then()` chain *already* returns a promise; you don't need to create yet another one. Read about the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

So remove this `new Promise` wrapper, and remove the final `.then()` call which was only there to call `resolve`:

```
function shop(id) {
    // return the promise returned by this promise chain:
    return fetch('/shop', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({id: id}) ,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json '}
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    });
}
```